# WAMP second virtual host not working/re-directing to first

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I got VH working fine.

Localhost and my first site (which is attached to a domain) work absolutely fine, no issues.

However I wanted to add a second site (3rd if you include localhost) to experiment with a new site. However after having added it, it simply seems to re-direct to the first site's domain. They are both wordpress installations (although the 3rd isnt installed yet as I cant access it) but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Here's my two relevant files;

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mysite"
    ServerName mysite.local
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/mysite">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mysite-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@mydomain.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/wordpress"
    ServerName mydomain.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.co.uk
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/wordpress">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/wordpress-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/wordpress-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

As explained.. localhost works, mydomain.co.uk works (name changed for privacy reasons but it works!). mysite.local does not it just redirects to mydomain.co.uk  ???? (I tried a bunch of names including mysite.localhost, etc etc-- nothing works! I don't care what the name is I just want to be able to access it, will be buying a domain for it soon).

Any help is appreciated. Thank-you!

Here's hosts file although it's pretty self explanatory;

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mysite.locals
127.0.0.1       mydomain.co.uk


::1 localhost
::1 mysite.local
::1 mydomain.co.uk
```

Comment: Are you sure, i would say it was more likely that `mydomain.co.uk` was the one that is not working?

Comment: 100% sure. mysite.locals in any browser (cleared cookies) will go to mydomain.co.uk -- It seems to be doing a redirect or something, as it'll say 'waiting for mydomain.co.uk' in the browser almost instantly. I've also tried restarting the server, restarting the DNS service all of the tips you've suggested in other threads!

Comment: Can't edit my comment. I've done a bit more prodding around.. decided to move the directory for my second site onto the desktop. Now what happens is, it loads up mydomain.co.uk/mysite So it's still redirecting to mydomain.co.uk but now it's thinking the mysite folder is on that site? Really confused!

Comment: Is this a typo? VH = `mysite.local` and HOSTS file = `mysite.locals` i.e. you have added an `s` on the IPV4 domain declaration